# Lambda funciton not triggering after s3 upload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to trigger a Lambda function after uploading a file.

Below I have defined the `file` Lambda function. Within it, a file is uploaded to s3. I then want the `process` Lambda function to triger. However, I cannot get it to trigger. Also, in AWS s3, the bucket Properties > Event notifications is empty.

My serverless.yml:

```
service: backend
frameworkVersion: "2"

package:
  exclude:
    - "frontend/**"

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    dockerFile: ./dockerfile

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  stage: dev
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
  environment:
    STORAGE_BUCKET: dev-storage-bucket-01392334
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:PutObjectAcl
        - s3:GetObject
        - s3:GetObjectAcl
        - s3:DeleteObject
      Resource: 
        - "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:*"
        - "arn:aws:s3:::*"

functions:
  process:
    handler: handler.process
    events:
      - s3:
        bucket: ${self:provider.environment.STORAGE_BUCKET}
        events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
        existing: true
  file:
    handler: handler.file
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: /file


resources:
  Resources:
    storage:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:provider.environment.STORAGE_BUCKET}
```

In my handler I have:

```
def process(event, context):

    print("in process")


def fcsfile(event, context):
    uploaded_file = event['body']

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    object = s3.Object(STORAGE_BUCKET, 'the_file_name')
    s3_response = object.put(Body=uploaded_file)

    print(s3_response)
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(response)
    }
    return response
```

When I do a CURL to the endpoint, the file gets uploaded to s3, but the process function is never triggered.

I have tried removing 'existing: true'. Same result. I have tried changing bucket name to something completely different e.g. 'dev-storage-bucket-99999999968686' but I then see the error:

```
An error occurred: S3BucketDevstoragebucket99999999968686 - dev-storage-bucket-99999999968686 already exists in stack
```

And no, the bucket does not exist.

What else can I try?

Comment: My test show that `dev-storage-bucket-99999999968686` exists.

Comment: Have you checked the bucket in the console to see whether that trigger was in fact created?

Comment: @404 how can i see a bucket trigger?

Comment: @Marcin I realised I have to deploy 3 times - the first 2 times give errors

Comment: @404 I checked that buckwt, i see nothing under Event notifications

Comment: You need to watch out for warnings/errors from sls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though you may have a small typo.

Replacing `events` with `event` in the `handler.process` block seems to work for me:

```
functions:
  process:
    handler: handler.process
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:provider.environment.STORAGE_BUCKET}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
```

When running the command with `events`, I receiving a warning from the serverless framework:
`Serverless: Configuration warning at 'functions.process.events[0]': unsupported function event`

Here is the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#setting-the-specific-trigger-event), which helped me find the correct syntax.

Comment: That may have been it, but I cannot see - now i see 'An error occurred: S3BucketDevstoragebucketzzz - dev-storage-bucket-zzz already exists'. That bucket does not exist in s3. I have deleted the entire stack through AWS console - I still get this error every tome I redeploy. At this point, im wondering if serverless framework is suitable - it is extraordinarily painful.

Comment: @mark unfortunately that error is coming from AWS, it doesn't come from the serverless framework. S3 bucket names must be globally unique, so it's likely another user saw this post and tested your sample code, which is why another user sees that it exists.

It's unfortunate if you find serverless technology painful, there are lots of resources to help learn and hone your cloud skills.